# Border-Radius for PDFMake

Tags: javascript, pdfmake

I'm wondering if anyone knows a hack or a way around setting a border-radius in PDFMake.

I have an image which I plan to have to a border-radius of about 4px.

```
{
    image: 'sampleImage.jpg',
    width: 150,
    height: 150,
},
```

There's no documentation for such.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make it static.

```
 {
      canvas: [
        {
          type: 'rect',
          x: 0,
          y: 0,
          w: 154,
          h: 154,
          r: 75,
          lineColor: 'black',
        },
      ],
    }
```

And add a position for your item:

```
  absolutePosition: {x: 45, y: 50}
```